# Bokeh:: Grid/TABS plots embed in flask

Tags: python, bokeh

Dears,

I have got a plot with three or more tabs. I am really sorry for the long code but I couldn't get it to work.

below is bokeh script file.

> Importing bokeh embed libraries

```
from bokeh. embed import components
 from bokeh.resources import CDN
```

> the last lines of the codes where tabs were merged.

```
############### TABS 1 ############
grid = gridplot([[V_Traffic, D_Traffic]])

tab1 = Panel(child=grid, title="LTE")

############### TABS 2 ############
p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")

############### TABS 3 ############

p3 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.triangle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="pink", alpha=0.5)
tab3 = Panel(child=p3, title="triangle")


tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2, tab3])  

## even with three tabs when I checked the length of len(components(tabs)) the answer was 2
## base on that I follow the lecture as is.

js, div = components(tabs)
cdn_js = CDN.js_files[0]
cdn_css = CDN.css_files[0]
below is my flask app code

from flask import Flask, render_template, cli
from stack_plot_grid_TAB_1 import js, div, cdn_js, cdn_css

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") 

def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/execute')
def execute_grid_tab():
    return render_template("stack_plot_grid_TAB_1.html", js=js, div=div, cdn_js=cdn_js, cdn_css=cdn_css)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> in the index file, I have given a link to another file once the user
>   selects the respective dashboards.
>
> below is code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/execute');
    window.open('C:\py\programs\bokeh\flask\templates\stack_plot_grid_TAB_1.html');">
    <button>execute python script for tabs</button></a>

</body>
</html>
```

> below is the code where my final plot should have shown.
>
> stack_plot_grid_TAB_1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href={‌{cdn_css|safe}} type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src={‌{cdn_js|safe}}></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>this is the new page.</button>
        {‌{js|safe}}
        {‌{div|safe}}


    </body>
    </html>
```

all the "html" files are saved in the "templates" folder.

in the end, it just says "this is the new page" and the graph is not visible. is there anything extra I need to do?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

@Riz.Khan your solution kinda gave me a north. If you create a def with all the plots in it and return the tabs instead the plots it will work just fine.

plot.py file

```
def nonOccupiers():
    dfn = pd.read_csv('BokehApp/Data/TT_nonOccupier.csv', delimiter='\t', index_col='Years')
    dfnt = dfn[['Total Transactions', 'Total Non-Occupiers']]
    rowX = '2010', '2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016', '2017', '2018'
    ....................
    t1 = Panel(child=pn, title='Overview')
    t2 = Panel(child=pne, title='Type of sale')
    t3 = Panel(child=pn3, title='Type of buyer')
    tabs = Tabs(tabs=[t1,t2,t3])
    return tabs
```

.app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from bokeh.embed import components
from plots import houseStockPlot, vacantPlot, Transactions, NewRegistered, nonOccupiers
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/')
def bokeh():
    script, div = components(houseStockPlot())
    script1, div1 = components(vacantPlot())
    script2, div2 = components(Transactions())
    script3, div3 = components(NewRegistered())
    script4, div4 = components(nonOccupiers())


    return render_template('bokeh.html', script=script, div=div, script1=script1,
    div1=div1, script2=script2, div2=div2, script3= script3, div3=div3, script4=script4, div4=div4)
```

I still working on the webapp, I am working by parts here just as a serial killer hahaha

.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!-- Bootstrap includes-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
       <!-- Bokeh includes-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/article.css') }}"  type="text/css" >
    {{ script|safe }}
    {{ script1|safe }}
    {{ script2|safe }}
    {{ script3|safe}}
    {{ script4|safe}}
    ..............................
<center>
<div class='bokeh'>
    {{ div4|safe }}

</div>
</center>
```

Just the relevant parts of the code added here.
The webapp project it is under this link [webapp](http://bokehflaskgcloud.appspot.com/) in case someone wants to have a look

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still interested, I found a workaround.

Since my bokeh app had TABS, I thought I could import them directly but couldn't find a solution how to import that.

As I mentioned earlier the code was perfect for a single graph, for example, TAB1 had grid graph, I was able to embed it perfectly with flask. so what I did

I created separate components for each TAB

```
js_TAB1, div_TAB1 = components(TAB1)
js_TAB2, div_TAB2 = components(TAB2)
js_TAB3, div_TAB3 = components(TAB3)

cdn_js = CDN.js_files[0]
cdn_css = CDN.css_files[0]
```

and then I create TABS in HTML.

and in each TAB I call my components separately

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'TAB1')">TAB1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'TAB2')">TAB2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'TAB3')">TAB3</button>

</div>

<div id="TAB1" class="tabcontent">

  {{div_TAB1|safe}}
  {{js_TAB1|safe}}
</div>

<div id="TAB2" class="tabcontent">

  {{div_TAB2|safe}}
  {{js_TAB2|safe}}
</div>

<div id="TAB3" class="tabcontent">

  {{div_TAB3|safe}}
  {{js_TAB3|safe}}

</div>
```

---

> note:: The code is not complete it's only for illustration. if someone
>   needs a complete code he can message me.

---

Best Regards